# Using De Moivre's Theorem to prove $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)$ trig identity

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck on trying to prove a trig identity using De Moivre's theorem.

I have to prove,
$$\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)$$

I am not sure where to even start, I broke the LHS down to $$\cos(3\theta) + i\sin(3\theta)$$

but I have no idea where to go from here, or if this is fully correct.

If I could get some pointers or a simple worked example  that I could follow it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De Moivre's formula reads
$$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)$$
Of course this identity implies the real part should be also equality. That is
$$\cos(n\theta)=\Re\{(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n\}$$
Hence we have
$$\cos(3\theta)=\Re\{\cos^3\theta+3i\cos^2\theta\sin\theta-3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta-i\sin^3\theta\}=\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta\sin^2\theta$$

Comment: I have reached the last line in your answer but where do I go from here?

Comment: @user2352274 Note that $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$

Comment: I got it, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\cos(n \phi) = \Re((\cos(\phi) + i\sin (\phi))^n)$$
Then use the Binomial Theorem to expand the expression.

(Where $\Re$ is the real part of the expression.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
Using de Moivre's identity:
$$ \cos 3\theta = \mathrm{Re}\left(e^{i3\theta}\right) $$
Now, $e^{i3\theta} = \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^3$ and (by definition of $e^{i\theta}$)
$$\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^3 = \left(\cos\theta+i\sin \theta\right)^3 $$
Expand the RHS (it's only a cube, so it's straightforward), and simplify the $i^3$, $i^2$; then take the real part to get $\mathrm{Re}\left(e^{i3\theta}\right)$.