# If $\sin(18^\circ)=\frac{a + \sqrt{b}}{c}$, then what is $a+b+c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, contest-math

If $\sin(18)=\frac{a + \sqrt{b}}{c}$ in the simplest form, then what is $a+b+c$?
$$ $$
**Attempt:**
$\sin(18)$ in a right triangle with sides $x$ (in front of corner with angle $18$ degrees), $y$, and hypotenuse $z$, is actually just $\frac{x}{z}$, then $x = a + \sqrt{b}, z = c$. We can find $y$ as
$$ y = \sqrt{c^{2}- (a + \sqrt{b})^{2}} $$
so we have 
$$ \cos(18) = \frac{y}{z} = \frac{\sqrt{c^{2}- (a + \sqrt{b})^{2}}}{c}$$

I also found out that
$$b = (c \sin(18) - a)^{2} = c^{2} \sin^{2}(18) - 2ac \sin(18) + a^{2}$$

I got no clue after this.

---

The solution says that $$ \sin(18) = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{4} $$

I gotta intuition that we must find $A,B,C$ such that
$$ A \sin(18)^{2} + B \sin(18) + C = 0 $$ 
then $\sin(18)$ is a root iof $Ax^{2} + Bx + C$, and $a = -B, b = B^{2} - 4AC, c = 2A$.

---

**Totally different. This question is not asking to prove that $sin(18)=(-1+\sqrt{5})/4$, that is just part of the solution.**

Comment: Probably you're supposed to use the fact that $18^\circ$ is the same as ${\pi\over10}$ radians.  I'd start looking at $\sin(5\theta)$

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

Comment: With $$\cos(90^\circ-x)=\sin x$$ and $$\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y$$

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438362/evaluate-cos-18-circ-without-using-the-calculator).

Comment: You probably want to stop $\frac{a+\sqrt{b}}{c}=\frac{na+\sqrt{n^2b}}{nc}$ from changing your $a+b+c$.

Comment: @YuiToCheng You can delete it now

Comment: @MariaMazur totally different question.. proving $sin(18)=...$ does contribute largely to the solution, but that is not the question.

Comment: This question was already closed, I reopen it by mistake and then reclose it.

Comment: @MariaMazur but it is not a duplicate. This is a contest math problem.

Comment: And what do you want now? To reopen it? Why? You already accept an aswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, let $AB=AC=x$. Note that $AD=CD=2$. As $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle CDB$, $\dfrac x2=\dfrac 2{x-2}$

So, $x^2-2x-4=0$ and hence $x=1+\sqrt{5}$.

$\sin18^\circ=\dfrac 1x=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}4$.

Comment: A beautifully simple answer!

Answer (score 8):

Let $A = 18°$
$$5A = 90°$$
$$⇒ 2A + 3A = 90˚$$
Taking sine on both sides, we get 
$$\sin 2A = \sin (90˚ - 3A) = \cos 3A $$
$$⇒ 2 \sin A \cos A = 4 \cos^3 A - 3 \cos A$$
$$⇒ 2 \sin A \cos A - 4 \cos^3A + 3 \cos A = 0 $$
$$⇒ \cos A (2 \sin A - 4 \cos^2 A + 3) = 0 $$
Dividing both sides by cos A
$$⇒ 2 \sin A - 4 (1 - sin^2 A) + 3 = 0$$
$$⇒ 4 \sin^2 A + 2 \sin A - 1 = 0$$
After solving this quadratic
$$ \sin18°=\frac{-1+√5}{4}$$

Comment: How you got $\cos 3A$?

Comment: $sin (90° - \theta) =cos\theta$

Comment: Not that........

Comment: So what explain more what you what to ask

Comment: In next line there is no $\cos 3A$. Where it go?

Comment: $cos3\theta=4cos^3\theta-3cos\theta$

Comment: And how you got that?

Comment: @MariaMazur $$\begin{align}\cos(3\theta)=\Re(e^{3i\theta})&=\Re((\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^3)\\&=\cdots\\&=\Re(4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta+3i\sin\theta-4i\sin^3\theta)\\&=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta\end{align}$$

Comment: Go through https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852122/picture-intuitive-proof-of-cos3-theta-4-cos3-theta-3-cos-theta/852230

Comment: @MariaMazur the relation can be obtained using simple sine and cosine rules:
$$\cos(3x) = \cos(x + 2x) =  \cos(x) \cos(2x) - \sin(x) \sin(2x) $$
$$ = \cos(x) (\cos^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x)) - 2 \sin^{2}(x) \cos(x) $$
$$ = \cos(x)(2 \cos^{2}(x)-1) - 2 (1 - \cos^{2}(x)) \cos(x)  $$
$$ = 4 \cos^{3}(x) - 3 \cos(x)$$

Comment: I know how to get $\cos 3x$. It is a missing detail which should be included in the answer. @AriefAnbiya

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**  This is now obsolete - it applies to the original version of the question, without the condition "in simplest form":

It's clear that $a+b+c$ is not determined, since $$\frac{2a+\sqrt{4b}}{2c}=\frac{a+\sqrt b}c$$but $$2a+4b+2c\ne a+b+c.$$

Comment: I like that all other answers went for lot of calculation, not one answering the original question while in fact it can be decided by simple considerations that the problem is missing constraints.

Comment: Explain me more please

Comment: @AbhishekKumar The point is that, from a technical point of view, the question cannot be answered. Consider that you could write $\frac{−1+\sqrt5}4$ as $\frac{−2+\sqrt{20}}8$ or $\frac{−100+\sqrt{50000}}{400}$, etc., each of which corresponds to a different result for $a+b+c$. The question would need to specify something like "... where $a,b,c \in \Bbb Z$ and $b$ is square free."

Comment: Yes you are correct, they must give some constraints to get the specific value of $a, b, c$

Comment: But $\frac{2a+ \sqrt{4b}}{2c}$ is not in simplest form...

Comment: @AriefAnbiya The point to my post was precisely that there must be a condition missing. Indeed, "in simplest form" was _added_ fifteen  hours after I posted this.

Answer (score 5):

Let $ABCDE$ be a regular pentagon.

In right triangle $GHC$ we see $\sin 18^{\circ} = {y\over 2x} $. Let $k=y/x$.

From triangle similarity of $GFC$ and $ACE$ we have $${x\over y} = {2x+y\over a}$$

and from triangle similarity of $BFC$ and $EDC$ we have $${a\over x} = {2x+y\over a}$$

Eliminate $a = {x^2\over y}$ and we get $$x^3 = y^2(2x+y)\implies k^3+2k^2-1 =(k-1)(k^2+k-1)=0 $$

Clearly $k\ne -1$ so $$k_{2,3} = {-1\pm \sqrt{5}\over 2} $$
and so $$\sin 18^{\circ} = {-1+ \sqrt{5}\over 4} $$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** This is a classic problem and probably a duplicate here, but I was unable to find another instance of this question as written. *Edit* [Found one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-prove-cos-frac2-pi-5-frac-1-sqrt54)

First, note that $\sin 18^\circ = \cos 72^\circ$; we find the latter.

Recall that (for $n \geq 2$) the sum of the $n$th roots of unity sum to zero, and taking real parts leaves $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \cos \left(\frac{k}{n} \cdot 360^\circ\right) = 0 .$$
Setting $n = 5$ and using the symmetry of the cosine function gives
$$1 + 2 \cos 72^\circ + 2 \cos 144^\circ = 0 .$$
Using the double angle formula---in particular that $$\cos 144^\circ = 2 \cos^2 72^\circ - 1$$ ---and substituting in the previous display equation gives a quadratic expression in $\cos 72^\circ$:
$$4 \cos^2 72^\circ + 2 \cos 72^\circ - 1 = 0 .$$
By the quadratic equation,
$$\cos 72^\circ = \frac{-2 + \sqrt{(2)^2 - 4 (4) (-1)}}{2(4)} = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{4} .$$
(To resolve the $\pm$ ambiguity it's enough to know that $\cos 72^{\circ} > 0$.)

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed this.