# Geometric significance of trigonometric functions for the complex plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have been able to find proofs for trigonometric identities (like the cosine triple angle formula) using De Moivre's theorem ([Using De Moivre's Theorem to prove $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)$ trig identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679570/using-de-moivres-theorem-to-prove-cos3-theta-4-cos3-theta-3-cos-the?noredirect=1&lq=1)). This being said, I'm having trouble understanding how a theorem with imaginary parts could "speak" for the reals as well? It's sort of a conceptual question but any math or pictures to clarify would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand your question, you are asking why results for complex numbers apply to real numbers.
It follow by the fact that you can identify $\mathbb{R}$ with the real axis of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ via the map $x\mapsto x+i0$.

About the De Moivre's formula, it uses the polar coordinates   and the angle $\theta$ is a real number which measures the angle with the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $\mathbb{R}^2$ is identified with $\mathbb{C}$ using the map $(a,b)\mapsto a+ib$.

Comment: thanks, I was struggling to put to words the geometric link between the use of an angle theta (trig functions) and the complex plane as well

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! I hope you have solved your problems. It is also possible to upvote if it was satisfactory ;-)